# Enabling Done Button When User Changes Values - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I am trying to make it to where if any value is typed on the keyboard without hitting the return key and two of the labels have been changed from "Select" to something else, the button up at the top becomes enabled. However, I have tried using an IBAction saying:

```
 - (IBAction)valuesChanged {
if (textField.text != nil && ![labelOne.text isEqualToString:@"Select"] && ![labelTwo.text isEqualToString:@"Select"]) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
 }

else {
    NSLog(@"No Success");
   }
}
```

But I have realized that this does not work because:

- The textfield does not work when I put the IBAction Sent Event as "Value Changed"
- The labels won't accept an action.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: does the valuesChanged method get called?

Comment: @ekims No, nothing gets NSLogged when I try and type into the textField. But either way that method wont work because the labels cant have an IBAction

Comment: no, but you can make them (labels) an Outlet and edit the text on valuesChanged. But first you need to either hook up your textFields with **valuesChanged** method or programmatically add the selector when creating the UITextFields.

Comment: @ekims Well I know how to change the values of the text I just need it to realize that once all of the requirements are met to change the done button to being enabled

Comment: Btw the two labels are being changed on the user side. Meaning they are allowed to change it however they want. Not program side. I've got it working to change the labels I just dont know how to make it to where it realizes that if all of them are changed to enable the done button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text field delegate method that tells you that the user is typing a character in the text field or otherwise changing its contents is `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. Implement it in your text field delegate and respond as appropriate. You will also just return YES.

One reason your original code couldn't be hooked up might be that you have not used the canonical form of an IBAction method; it should be

```
 - (IBAction)valuesChanged:(id)sender {
```

Another problem in your original code is that a UITextField does not emit Value Changed. What you wanted was Editing Changed. But the delegate method works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `UITextField` delegate methods.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Comment: But what happens if I type into the textfield and then change the values of the two labels? Then the done button will not be enabled until I go back and select the textField again